# Trimming newlines from promt.get in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, raspbian

So I'm in a console (raspbian lite to be exact, but I think that shouldn't matter). And I'm asking the user of my js program to give some data (name, date of birth etc). This data is then carried on to a python program.

Problem: once in python, I get newlines pasted at the end of my variable's values.
I could just trim it in python, but I prefer to do it earlier in javascript.

This my code:
As you can see I've already tried replacing the newlines, which doesn't work.

```
prompt.get(['name', 'date_start', 'date_end'], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
            return onErr(err);
    };

    console.log('Command-line input received:');
    console.log('  Name ' + result.name);
    console.log('  Start date:  ' + result.date_start);
    console.log('  End date:  ' + result.date_end);

    var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
    var pyshell = new PythonShell('new_try_crypto.py');

    pyshell.send(result.name.replace('\n', ''));
    pyshell.send(result.date_start.replace('\n', ''))
    pyshell.send(result.date_end.replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: [String.prototype.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim). Although since your passing stuff to the python shell, it's possible that the newlines are being added dy the shell itself...

Comment: @JaredSmith Indeed, it's also possible they are significant or necessary (knowing how shells tend to work).

Comment: @Panga97: think you're going to have to `rstrip` it in Python then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim):

```
prompt.get(['name', 'date_start', 'date_end'], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
            return onErr(err);
    };

    console.log('Command-line input received:');
    console.log('  Name ' + result.name);
    console.log('  Start date:  ' + result.date_start);
    console.log('  End date:  ' + result.date_end);

    var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
    var pyshell = new PythonShell('new_try_crypto.py');

    pyshell.send(result.name.trim());
    pyshell.send(result.date_start.trim())
    pyshell.send(result.date_end.trim())
};
```

Comment: In that case Jared's comment is likely correct: they probably come from the shell itself, which isn't surprising since newlines are often used to delineate end of input/output.